# Inequality involving integrals of powers of sine

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality

The problem is to prove that:

For every $ k \geq 0 $ and $ \frac{\pi}{2} \leq \alpha \leq \pi $, 
$$
\bigg(\int_{[0,\alpha - \frac{\pi}{2}] \cup [\frac{\pi}{2}, \alpha]} \sin^{k} \theta \, d\theta \bigg) \bigg(\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin^{k} \theta \, d\theta \bigg)^{k+1} \leq \bigg(\int_{0}^{\alpha} \sin^{k} \theta \, d\theta \bigg)^{k+2}
$$

For example, when $ k = 0 $, this becomes $ (2\alpha-\pi)\pi \leq \alpha^2 $, which is trivial.

I am pretty sure this inequality holds for every $ k \geq 0 $, but couldn't prove.

Any comment would be appreciated!